# Trouble connecting to SQL server using Java

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

This is what I've written as part of my code:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
String host1 = "<URL/Connection path string>";
String uname1= "<User name>";
String pwd1 = "<Password>";
Connection con1 =DriverManager.getConnection(host1,uname1,pwd1);
Statement stmt1 = con1.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt1.executeQuery("<Query>");
```

I've used the following jar files: *jtds-1.3.0, sqljdbc-4.1.5605, sqljdbc4-4.0*

when I ran the code, I got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection to the host <host-name>, named instance <instance-name> failed. Error: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out". Verify the server and instance names and check that no firewall is blocking UDP traffic to port 1434.  For SQL Server 2005 or later, verify that the SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.getInstancePort(SQLServerConnection.java:3589)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.primaryPermissionCheck(SQLServerConnection.java:1225)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:972)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at first_doc.main(first_doc.java:28)
```

as far as I know, there is no firewall that's blocking traffic.

Also, do I need to add Port number as part of the Connection URL?

Edit: I use SQL server version 2008

I cannot find Protocols for SQLEXPRESS in the Configuration Manager

[image]

Comment: Is your actual code as is? I mean with `String host1 = "<URL/Connection path string>";` and stuff?

Comment: Is your sql server running on the background ?

Comment: @Cid no, I've modified it for privacy reasons.

Comment: @Arty, yes it is

Comment: @TRV ok, I just wanted to be sure :)

Comment: Did you have any successfull connections to the server via Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio or something like that?

Comment: @Cid this is the syntax I've used: "jdbc:sqlserver://<Server_name>\\<DB_Name>;databaseName=<DB_Name>". I've also tried "jdbc:sqlserver://<Server_name>\\<DB_Name>:<Port_number>;databaseName=<DB_Name>"

Comment: @YuriyTsarkov, yes, that's exactly what I'm using actually

Comment: Usually post is required in the URL

Comment: `jdbc:sqlserver://<Server_name>\\<INSTANCE_Name>`

Comment: @Arty, I have modified my question. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the steps that you need to do. If you already did this please check again.

- Download latest MSSQL JDBC driver from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx
- Referenced the 2 JAR files in my project:

  sqljdbc.jar and sqljdbc4.jar

  (I'm not yet sure if both of the above are required or just one..)
- Make sure the SQL Server Browser windows service is running
- Open SQL Server Configuration Manager and go to Protocols for SQLEXPRESS under SQL Server Network Configuration. Right-click on TCP/IP and choose Properties.

  Set Enabled = YES.
- While you're there, click on IP Addresses tab and find the section IP All.

  Set TCP Port to 1433.
- Add **sqljdbc_auth.dll** to your PATH Environment Variable. In my case:

  ```
  D:\Java\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\auth\x64
  ```
- Copy the **sqljdbc_auth.dll** to your JDK directory. In my case:

  ```
  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin
  ```

Comment: I finally got it! I had missed the last step, adding the dll file to the JDK directory. Also had to change CLASSPATH to reference to the sqljdbc JAR file. Thanks to all who tried to help!